# Chat Screen/Window Layout Design

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm need advice on how to do this (best practice way):

[image: chat screen design[][1]]

I'm using XCode 6.1.1 using Swift with autolayout ENABLED.
So in the picture I already set the layout that way.
Note that in the scrollview, I put `UITableView` along with another `UIView` which contain a `UITextField` in it

I also already implement this: [How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

So here's my code:

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidShow:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidHide:", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardDidShow(aNotification: NSNotification)
{
    var info: NSDictionary = aNotification.userInfo!
    var kbSize: CGSize = (info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)?.CGRectValue() as CGRect!).size

    var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0)
    svBody.contentInset = contentInsets
    svBody.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

func keyboardDidHide(aNotification: NSNotification)
{
    var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    svBody.contentInset = contentInsets
    svBody.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

The problem is when I run it, I can also scroll my `viewBottom` behind the keyboard which I don't want that.

[image: result[][2]]

What I'm trying to achieve are:

- I need the `viewBottom` to stick on top of the keyboard
- Only `myTable` that can be scrolled

How can I do this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out by myself.

Here's the code for everyone to use:

```
func registerForKeyboardNotifications()
{
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidShow:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardDidHide:", name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification, object: nil)
}

func keyboardDidShow(aNotification: NSNotification)
{
    var info: NSDictionary = aNotification.userInfo!
    var kbSize: CGSize = (info.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)?.CGRectValue() as CGRect!).size

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(kbSize.height, 0, 0, 0)
        self.myTable.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.myTable.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var contentOffsetSV: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, kbSize.height)
        self.svBody.contentOffset = contentOffsetSV

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })

}

func keyboardDidHide(aNotification: NSNotification)
{
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        var contentInsets: UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        self.myTable.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.myTable.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var contentOffsetSV: CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        self.svBody.contentOffset = contentOffsetSV

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Good to share ;)
Cheers,

Adrian